# add link with bbm pin in my website after click on it from mobile browser bbm app open and add new contact

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to let website visitors click on PIN code after click automatically open bbm application with add new contact with same PIN
I've tried this code:

```
<a href="PIN:1234a567"><b>pin:24D25699</b></a>
```

onclick open bbm app without add new contact

Comment: Where is your code???

Comment: sorry this is my first time adding question, here is the code: <a href="PIN:1234a567"><b>pin:24D25699</b></a>

Comment: simple as that: <a href=”bbmi://2100000A”>Start BBM Chat or Invite User</a>